# Perl processing a trillion records

Tags: algorithm, perl

Looking for some advice or insight on what I consider a simple method in PERL to compare text files to one another.

Lets assume you have 90,000 text files that are all structured similarly, say they have a common theme with a small amount of unique data in each.

My logic says to simply loop through the files (breaking into 1000 lines for simplicity), then loop through the # of files ... 90,000 - then loop through the 90,000 files again to compare to each other. This becomes a virtually endless loop of a bazillion lines or processes.

Now the mandatory step here is to "remove" any line that is found in any file except the file we are working on. The ultimate goal is to scrub all the files down to content that is unique across the entire collection, even if it means some files end up empty.

I am saying files, but this could be rows in a database, or elements in an array. (I`ve tried all.) The fastest solution so far has been to load all the files into mysql, then run
UPDATE table SET column=REPLACE(column, find, replace); Also tried Parallel::ForkManager when working with mysql.

The slowest approach actually led to exhausting my 32 GB of ram - that was loading all 90k files into an array. 90k files didnt work at all, smaller batches like 1000 works fine, but then doesnt compare to the other 89,000.

Server specs if helpful: Single Quad-Core E3-1240 4Cores x 3.4Ghz w/ HT 32GB DDR3 ECC RAM 1600MHz 1x256SSD

So how does an engineer solve this problem? I am just PERL hacker...

Comment: You might want to read about how `rsync` uses rolling checksums to compare source and destination files so it just sends the parts of the files that have changed. You may be able to adapt that into an algorithm for your task.

Comment: That is a good idea... Looking into it. I also forgot to add that in theory the files get smaller as it goes, so it should speed up.

Comment: This is called a Rolling Hash, and there is a perl module - i`ll test to see if it is helpful here. https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::RabinKarp

Comment: What is the goal of the comparison? Do you want to find identical files?

Comment: I want to "scrub" all duplicate content from all files, leaving each file with only unique data (lines) that isnt found in others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag every line with the filename (and maybe the line number) and sort all the lines using [`Sort::External`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort%3a%3aExternal). Then you can read the sorted records in order and write only a single unique line to the result files.

Comment: This one is running nicely on my test of 90,000. Basically takes about 20 minutes to build the array, then 3-4 minutes to run through it and put the results into a db.

Answer (score 2):

A Bloom filter is perfect for this, if you can handle arbitrarily small error.

To quote wikipedia: "A Bloom filter is a space-efficient probabilistic data structure that is used to test whether an element is a member of a set. False positive matches are possible, but false negatives are not; i.e. a query returns either 'possibly in set' or 'definitely not in set'."

In essence, you'll use k hashes to hash each row to k spots on a bit array. Each time you encounter a new row, you are guaranteed you haven't seen it if at least one of the k hashed indices has a '0' bit. You can read up on Bloom filters to see how to size the array and choose k to make false positives arbitrarily small.

Then you go through your files, and either delete rows where you get a positive match, or copy the negative match rows into a new file.

Comment: I am going to test this one out next, now that I have a sort of benchmark from Sort::External - thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the items using an external merge sort algorithm and remove the duplicates on the merge phase.

Actually, you can do that efficiently just calling the `sort` command with the `-u` flag. From Perl:

```
system "sort -u @files >output";
```

Your `sort` command may provide several adjustable parameters to improve its performance. For instance, the number of parallel processes or the amount of memory it can allocate.